# pq_query error on update

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-update, updates, case-when

I'm new to postresql and i am ashamed to recognize that i am not sure how tot execute correctly an update .

Every time I am trying to pg_query($update); it gives me this : Query failed: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction .

Before this update I have executed a select query .

The select statement retrieves 50000 rows from the database. To be even more specific I am trying to execute a when /case update on 1000 rows. The query is well-formed I have tested it .

```
$sqlstr = "update abcd set country = CASE" ;
$temp = "";
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($cnt < 1000) {
        $country = exec('geoiplookup '.$myrow['ip']);
        $temp .= " WHEN id = ".$myrow['id']." then '".$country."'";
        $cnt++;
    }
    else {
        $sqlstr = $sqlstr.$temp." END ; ";
        pg_query($sqlstr);
        $temp = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: $sqlstr = "update abcd set country = CASE" ;  
$temp = "";  
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result))   
{  
     
 if ($cnt < 1000)     
 {   
  $country = exec('geoiplookup '.$myrow['ip']);    
  $temp .= " WHEN id = ".$myrow['id']." then     '".$country."'";   
  $cnt++;  
 }  
 else  
 {  
  $sqlstr =  $sqlstr.$temp." END ; ";   
  pg_query($sqlstr);  
     
  $temp = "";   
 
 }  
}

Comment: 1: update your question, not add a comment, as formatting is a pain etc.
2: Somewhere along the way you set the transaction to read only.  Could have been a tool you're using etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqlstr = "update abcd set country = CASE" ;
$temp = "";
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

    if ($cnt < 1000)
    {
        $country = exec('geoiplookup '.$myrow['ip']);
        $temp .= " WHEN id = ".$myrow['id']." then  '".$country."'"; 
        $cnt++;
    }
    else
    {
        $sqlstr =  $sqlstr.$temp." END ; ";
        pg_query($sqlstr);

        $temp = "";

    }
}
```